# Advantage of using @Test(enabled = false) over the commenting @Test annotation in TestNG

Tags: java, testng

I know that `@Test(enabled = false)` will ignore the test for the annotated method.
But why can't we just Comment the annotation to ignore. 
I mean what is the advantage of using `@Test(enabled = false)` over the commenting  `@Test` annotation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only difference is related to [programming style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_style).

Commenting source code is commonly recognized as violation. Commented code should be removed from source code.

There is violation *Avoid commented-out lines of code* in [Sonarqube](http://www.sonarqube.org/) with nice description

> > Here are the main reasons why commented code is a code smell :
>
> - It always raises more questions than it gives answers
> - Everybody will forget very quickly how relevant the commented code is
> - This is distraction when going down the code as it stops the flow of eyes
> - It is a bad SCM engine : Subversion, CVS and Git are really more trustworthy !
> - The simple fact of understanding why code was commented out in the first place can take a lot of time

Example real case: [Code cleanup: remove commented out code](https://bugs.launchpad.net/goobi-production/+bug/937795)